# php-fpm docker could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, dockerfile

I Googled a lot, then how to make a dockerfile in the prod, but I don't like one thing, then the second. Now it gives an error that the mysql driver is not found. Can you tell me what needs to be done to make everything work without anything superfluous? I haven't worked with php itself, there are a lot of new and not clear things for me here (with the same extensions). You need to at least pack everything in Docker so that everything works on the prod

Dockerfile:

```
FROM composer as builder

WORKDIR /app/

COPY composer.json composer.lock ./

RUN composer install --no-dev --ignore-platform-reqs --no-scripts

FROM php:8.0.2-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libzip-dev\
    libonig-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl

RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /var/www

RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www
COPY --chown=www:www --from=builder /app/vendor /var/www/vendor

USER www

EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

There is a lot of excess in the dockerfile backend, I will clean it up, now we need to fix everything

Response from backend:

```json
{
  "message": "could not find driver (SQL: select * from clients where (telegram_id = something) limit 1)",
  "exception": "Illuminate\Database\QueryException",
  "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php",
  "line": 760
}
```

Vendor himself (as well as vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php ) generated when `composer install`

If it's important, here's the generated Connection.php: https://gist.github.com/ApppleTurnover/95dcfdf43743cf1eccea8a1db3ecac16

`composer.json`:

```json
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0.2",
        "ext-gd": "*",
        "google/apiclient": "*",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^9.19",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.7",
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "*",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^5.9"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Added to composer `RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql`

However, it didn't work, I'm not sure if I'm looking in the right direction at all

PS The command above was worked out for a very long time, it is not clear why. Can you also tell me
PSS Also, there may be edits and errors on the docker file, you can tell me, I will be grateful

Comment: _"it gives an error that the mysql driver is not found"_ This is not quite true. It does not specify _which_ driver is missing, which begs the question -- which database is your app configured to use? What's in your DB_CONNECTION variable?

Comment: @AlexHowansky mysql, I pointed a little lower than I was trying to fix this problem (pdo_mysql)

Comment: Put `docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql` in the Dockerfile and rebuild the image.

Comment: Where should this be done? In the composer image or in php?

Comment: Alex is right, `docker-php-exe-install pdo_mysql` will solve this problem, thanks